# Protractor unable to find config file: Error: Cannot find module '/protractor/protractor.conf_sanity.js'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Protractor version: `5.4.2`

Present working directory: `/protractor`

CLI to run the test: `sudo -u protractor xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1280x1024x24" -a protractor $@`

File is present in the directory: `-rw-rw-rw-. 1 jenkins jenkins 5528 Nov 23 07:14 protractor.conf_sanity.js`

The test is failing with below error:

```
[06:37:35] E/configParser - Error code: 105

[06:37:35] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file protractor.conf_sanity.js

[06:37:35] E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module '/protractor/protractor.conf_sanity.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js:135:26)
    at Object.initFn [as init] (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:93:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js:226:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
```

I have been scratching my head for a few days for this. What am I missing?

I add `pwd` and `ls -lrt $@` to the entrypoint script and it is finding the file.

`/protractor`

`-rw-rw-rw-. 1 jenkins jenkins 5528 Nov 23 07:14 protractor.conf_dev_sanity.js`

Comment: clearly it cannot find the module, perhaps the path to the file is wrong? can you share how are you trying to locate the file?

Comment: did you tried : https://github.com/hortonworks/docker-e2e-protractor/issues/5?

Comment: @RameshRajendran My project is volumed to the docker container correctly. I added `pwd` and `ls -lrt $@` to the entrypoint script. It seems to find the file.

Comment: @JoaquinCasco I added `pwd` and `ls -lrt $@` to the entrypoint script. It seems to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in a dark...

Your CLI command looks weird to me

I start tests like so

`xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 ${SCREEN_RES}" protractor protractor.conf.js`

Can you try this?

---

As to WHAT is happening I think it looks for `/protractor/protractor.conf_sanity.js` while already in working directory... essentially under `/protractor/protractor/protractor.conf_sanity.js`. But no idea WHY it's happening

Comment: The second part of your answer helped me fix this. It indeed looks for `/protractor/protractor.conf_sanity.js` while already in `/protractor` directory. I changed the `WORKDIR` in the image from `/protractor` to `/` and run the tests like `cd /protractor && sudo -u protractor xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1280x1024x24" -a` and it works.